# Is it ok to add jars from 2 diff struts versions of Struts2?

Tags: struts2

I am trying to run a simple Struts2 example from javabrains in youtube, but the jars he said to add is not present in Struts2 2.3.3 but is present in Struts 2.5.10.1.  So I added and run but for some reason i get this error

```
SEVERE: Exception starting filter struts2 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
        org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecteFilter
```

Comment: Using struts2 libraries of different versions is bound to cause problems.

Comment: Please specify the jar name.

Comment: Do not use multiple versions of S2 artifacts in the same project. (For that matter it's generally bad to have multiple versions of *anything* on the classpath unless you're explicitly shadowing them.) In any case, something's more wrong than usual, because there is no `StrutsPrepareAndExecteFilter` class in *any* S2 version, because that's the wrong spelling. So you probably screwed up your filter config.